# Flickr: How to use flickr.photos.geo.getLocation in python or any language?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, flickr, phpflickr, flickrj

I used the following code to get Latitude and Longitude in python in pycharm environment as

```
import flickr

api_key = u'xxxxx'
secret_api_key = u'xxxxxx'

photoID=8636126004

for photo in flickr.photos.geo.getLocation(api_key=api_key,photo_id=photoID,extras="geo"):
    print (photo.attrib['id'])
    print (photo.attrib['latitude'])
    print (photo.attrib['longitude'])
```

But I get the below error as

> for photo in flickr.geo.getLocation(api_key=api_key,photo_id=photoID,
>   extras="geo"): AttributeError: module 'flickr' has no attribute
>   'photos'

Guide me to resolve this error and to get Latitude and Longitude in python. If the suggestion maybe in java or php etc. also helps me. Thanks in advance.